# Using REPLACE to replace a character on an unique VARCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, varchar, unique-constraint

I have a situation where I need to remove the character '.' from a VARCHAR with a uniqueness constraint in a specific table.  I would prefer to do this in SQL over custom application code.  I have the logic to making the change, but i'm struggling on how to overcome the uniqueness constraint on the VARCHAR.

Here's my test table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableName] (
    [TableNameID]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TableInfo]     VARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [unq_TableName] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([TableInfo] ASC)
)
```

Here's the logic for doing the replace (without handling the uniqueness constraint):

```
UPDATE TableName
SET TableInfo = REPLACE(TableInfo, '.', '_')
WHERE TableInfo LIKE '%.%'
```

I'm trying to overcome a test I created with the following dataset:

```
TableNameID | TableInfo
-------------------------
     1      |  Test
     2      |  Test.
     3      |  Test_
     4      |  Test__
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about this uniqueness. I have a doubt if you remove the point in the second record then the first and the second will be the same and you have a duplicate record. My concern or doubt is why do you have duplicate data or you want to find this duplicates to delete them?

Comment: My hope here is to figure out its a duplicate and further modify the VARCHAR prior to setting it on the table...  so in the case of 2, I would modify it with Test_, see its still a duplicate, modify it to Test__, see its still a duplicate and finally settle on Test___.  I'm open to other ideas as well.  Dropping the constraint can be done, but I would have to add it back as soon as I'm done.  Its necessary for the application's logic.

Answer (score 1):

SHOULD it be unique?  If the answer is 'yes' then you have to somehow figure out how to de-duplicate the data.  In your example, what do you do with ID 3?  You're going to create two records with TableInfo = 'Test_'. You have to develop some way of combining or eliminating one of them.

If the answer is 'no' then simply drop the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. Create a count query and in the where use the count to select only the values with less than 2
2. This result are the record with out duplicates
3. Use this query as the source for the update
4. Run your update query, this will work only with the data no duplicated and the update will run    correctly.

You can create another query with the count more than one to find the duplicates and work with them if you like.

This is an example:

```
UPDATE  TableToUpdate
SET     columnToUpdate = REPLACE(columnToUpdate, '.', '')
FROM    ( SELECT    COUNT(*) AS Count ,
                    ID
          FROM      TableToUpdate
          GROUP BY  columnToUpdate
          HAVING    ( COUNT(*) < 2 )
        ) AS QueryData
WHERE   tableToUpdate.ID = QueryData.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works if you know the PK of a row to be updated:-

```
declare @unique varchar(50)
set @unique = ''

while 1=1 begin
    set @unique+='_'
    update t set 
        t.TableInfo = replace(t.TableInfo, '.', @unique)
    from dbo.tablename t
    where t.TableNameID=2 --t.tableinfo like '%.%'
    and not exists(
        select *
        from dbo.TableName csq
        where csq.TableInfo = replace(t.TableInfo, '.', @unique)
    )
    if @@rowcount=1
        break
end
```

The code is fragile and would fail if, for example, the width of the TableInfo column was insufficient to create a unique key by appending multiple underscores.

Enumerating a cursor over a recordset of rows that need updating - and then calling this code for each PK should be trivial (or converting it into a UDF and calling it with a `cross apply`).

I'll have to think harder about how to make it work set based.  I may come back with a different answer when I've had some sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Juan.  Your post inspired me and got me thinking about counts.

I came up with the following (not as compact as your, but it works).  I'll still have to deal with the "possible" length issue, but I can handle that.

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableName WHERE TableInfo LIKE '%.%')
BEGIN
DECLARE @oldInfo VARCHAR(128)
SET @oldInfo = (SELECT TOP 1 TableInfo FROM TableName WHERE TableInfo LIKE '%.%')

DECLARE @newInfo VARCHAR(128)
SET @newInfo = REPLACE(@oldInfo, '.', '_')

DECLARE @count VARCHAR(128)
SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName WHERE TableInfo LIKE @newInfo + '%')

IF @count > 0
BEGIN
    IF (LENGTH(@newInfo) + LENGTH(@count) <= 128)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TableName
        SET TableInfo = @newInfo + @count
        WHERE TableInfo = @oldInfo
    END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE TableName
    SET TableInfo = @newInfo
    WHERE TableInfo = @oldInfo
END
END
```

Comment: Looks nice, maybe you can use the query searching the value to update and get the id of the record, the use the id in the where just to be sure you are editing the same record. Glad to help.